# Is stack.imgur.com hosting still free for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, imgur

The image hosting at stack.imgur.com used to be [free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90342/178179) for Stack Exchange. Is it still free?

Comment: `We engaged in a 1 year agreement to formally support imgur` doesn't really sound like "free" to me?

Comment: See Sam's comment [on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), @Pëkka: *"Well imgur is kindly provided to us for free"*.

Comment: I was indeed referring to Sam's comment, I guess I should have quoted in the question's details

Answer (score 21):

The imgur hosting for Stack Exchange was never free to begin with. The API alone is not free for commercial use, as can be seen [here](https://market.mashape.com/imgur/imgur-9/pricing):

> [image]

With the amount of traffic on Stack Exchange sites I doubt that even the Mega package is enough so it might as well cost more than $500 per month, not to mention the dedicated domain.

Comment: [Sure about that?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) *"Alan Schaaf, the man behind Imgur, generously provided us a network-wide “pro” account that keeps any images hosted through our websites around indefinitely."* Sounds free, or at least cheap, to me.

Comment: Ah, Sam commented on the above link: *"Well imgur is kindly provided to us for free, we got no such offers from S3 or imageshack. The API is solid / complete and very easy to use."*

Comment: We have a deal with good working relationship and deal with them, it's not free but we are quite happy with the arrangement.  The imgur guys are still awesome to work with and implement the occasional custom feature for us as well.

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks, can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Nick so it's a custom made contract? Nice anyway!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Could you please update the URL. It has now expired.