# Should I upload images for other users with low reputation?

Tags: support, new-users, privileges, images

How should you react in the case where a new user posts a question to which an image would significantly contribute, but he mentions that he can not upload one due to low reputation? Is it best practice to

- Offer to accept the image (by email?), upload it and add it to the question through an edit?
- Point to image-hosting services?
- Upvote the question so he gets enough reputation to add it himself?
- Ignore the question and move on?
- Or ...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would ask the user to upload the image (they can still use SE's image uploader), and include the link in the question. Then you or another user with the editing privilege can vet the image and update the formatting to inline the image: `![image title](imagelink)`.

Often I find that users have included a link to another image host in the question from the start, despite not being able to inline the image. If you see that, it's a good idea to copy the image over to stack.imgur.com while editing; that ensures the image will live as long as the question does.

Comment: They don't need to upload it elsewhere. Even without the reputation, you can always use our on-site uploader - you just can't submit the post with the uploaded image formatted as an image.

Comment: That makes _far_ too much sense, @animuson. Editing...

Comment: If the image is on Imgur, but not stack.imgur.com is that a potential issue?

Comment: Yes, @Andy, I believe so. Imgur normally expires images after a while, but my understanding is that [those images on stack.imgur.com which are linked to from an SE site will be preserved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213547/is-stack-imgur-com-hosting-still-free-for-stack-exchange#comment687746_213548).