# If I use an imgur image in a comment, may the link break at some point in the future?

Tags: discussion, imgur

I expect that imgur images in an answer or question not to disappear (since avoiding 404 images is one of the main reasons behind using imgur).

If I use an imgur image (`i.stack.imgur.com/…`) in a comment, may the link to the image break at some point in the future?

Comment: Unlike imgur.com ordinary links, which indeed expire after a while without any views, SE got a dedicated premium account on imgur ensuring the images will never expire, even with zero views.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, I was afraid that i.stack.imgur.com would get cleaned from time to time to avoid people using it outside Stack Exchange questions and answers. Stack Exchange indeed has a [deal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213547/178179) with imgur.

Comment: Cheers, that part is answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94710/can-i-should-i-delete-unused-images-from-imgur). :)

Comment: Hold on a second, isn't this supposed to be [support] rather than [discussion]?

Comment: @dorukayhan no clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Imgur is really unlikely to shut down in the next few years (or even decades), so `i.stack.imgur.com/insertImageIDHere.png` links should be safe.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure there is no garbage collector removing images that are not present in either question or answers.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Nope. We don't ever prune images. It would have to be manually deleted.