# How much of Stack's imgur image-ID space has been consumed?

Tags: discussion, imgur, architecture

Images posted to Stack's imgur space have the following URL structure:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apnr6.png

This implies to me that images stored there have a five-character ID, with at least 62 possible characters at each position in the ID.  So, that gives around a billion unique IDs.

I've been curious for a while now: what fraction of these IDs are now allocated?  How rapidly is this ID space being consumed? Per questions, e.g., [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94710/can-i-should-i-delete-unused-images-from-imgur) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281096/if-i-use-an-imgur-image-in-a-comment-may-the-link-break-at-some-point-in-the-fu), there is (or was) no garbage collection implemented to scrub "dead" images, so at *some* point there's presumably going to be a crunch on new IDs.

How close are we to the point of exhausting the imgur image ID space?

Comment: Why are you assuming that 5 alpha-nums won't go into 6? And then 7? And then 8?

Comment: @Oded Because of the [suffixing capability](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3048/11367) to change the display size of an image. And, yes, I know that it would probably work to extend the alpha-nums by just imposing the rule that no extended base ID is allowed to have any of the suffix characters at the end. But, I have no idea if imgur is set up to allow that.

Comment: This isn't stack only, whole of imgur is built this way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard <nod>, that's what I thought. So, it seems like it would make the issue even *more* pressing for imgur at large. 1bb IDs is a *small small small* number for the whole world.

Comment: @hBy2Py well, I wrote a random imgur image generator, that just generates random  5 characters string and display it as imgur image. It got about 30% success, i.e. looks like 30% of the possible images are already allocated.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess maybe imgur uses multiple subdomains to provide additional ID spaces -- perhaps they'd just issue `i2.stack.imgur.com`?

Comment: [Here is the JS code if you're interested](https://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/kq5ngx86/embedded/js/), you can click "edit in JSFiddle" to see it in action, but keep in mind that  since it's totally random, you might get NSFW images there.

Comment: *”Because of the suffixing capability to change the display size of an image.”* This is not a problem. Add two characters instead. If the URL has 5 or 6 characters, it’s the 5-character code. If it has 7 or 8, it’s the 7-character code.

Comment: Aha, that's a slick way to handle it -- odd-length IDs imply no suffix, even-length IDs imply a suffix is present. Thanks @CrisLuengo!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of the latest backup mirror we took of imgur's data in mid-February, we had a total of 6,713,997 images hosted by imgur, totaling about 600GB.

The 5 character namespace imgur uses has 916,132,832 (62^5) possibilities, which puts us a bit under 1% utilization of the namespace.

Comment: What is this backup for? If imgur will decide to delete images one day? I thought you give imgur full control and trust over images. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard If imgur goes belly-up one day. Or, if imgur's backup discipline/hygiene is less than perfect. Or, if ....

Comment: @hBy2Py nailed it - it's not that we don't trust imgur, but we're paid to be paranoid about this kind of thing, and it makes sense to have a slightly-outdated copy under our own roof for both reasonably likely possibilities (an extended outage in S3, which imgur uses) and some of our more wild Mad Max-inspired business continuity scenarios.

Comment: @ShaneMadden There's no backup quite like one you have total physical control over.

Comment: [Back them up. Again.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395024/stack-exchange-s-image-hosting-arrangement-with-imgur-is-ending-advance-notice)

Answer (score 3):

By my current estimate (from searching IDs from 00000 to 1w000ish), at the time of this writing (Jan 2024), it's more like 2.44%. That is, assuming that whatever ID-assignment function is being used has a uniform distribution (and it does appear to).

Comment: How did you check whether certain ID is assigned or not? Is the code available anywhere?

Comment: Good to have this update. Now we have three data points! 0% in... 2014?, ~1% @ 2017, and 2.4% in 2024. :-D