# How does Stack Exchange use Imgur for profile photos?

Tags: support, profile-picture, imgur

I can see that the link to my profile image is `https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5UJS.jpg?s=48&g=1`.

I have not seen this to be a public feature of Imgurs API as you have to at least sign up on Imgur first from what I am aware of.

Is this just a Stack Exchange/Imgur relationship thing or is it usable by everyone?

Comment: See [New Image Upload Support](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/)... [Any details about stack.imgur.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90342/307988) and [Is stack.imgur.com hosting still free for Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213547/307988)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, as explained in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/) Stack Exchange is a Imgur customer:

> Alan Schaaf, the man behind Imgur, generously provided us a network-wide “pro” account that keeps any images hosted through our websites around indefinitely.

They have their own sub domain on Imgur (`i.stack.imgur.com`), where images never expire for example. Profile pictures are uploaded automatically to Imgur if you set one from your profile. They use the [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/) to upload images.

It is possible that profile pictures are coming from other sources though. For example when you log in with your Facebook ID, it will load the images directly from the Facebook CDN.

You can use the Stack Exchange Imgur account to upload images from the upload dialog when editing posts. That is the only way to upload images there.

Comment: Is this exclusive to Stack Exchange?

Comment: @NooBskie Updated.

Comment: @NooBskie no, there are [3300 subdomains for imgur.com](https://archive.is/*.imgur.com), not 100% sure how one can get it, probably only by special request, but still... SE is far from being the only one to have it.

Comment: That's what I was trying to figure out thanks @ShadowWizard