# Why not SVG-capable editor?

Tags: discussion, editor

Pasting a definition like:

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="247.7px" height="83.7px" viewBox="0 0 247.7 83.7" enable-background="new 0 0 247.7 83.7"
     xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<rect id="square_1_" x="0.5" y="0.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="137.3" height="82.7"/>
<circle id="circle_1_" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="205.8" cy="41.8" r="41.3"/>
</svg>
```

Would allow to directly describe problems visually easily, while right now that can be done through image insertion:

[image: png]

Why can't the editor allow inline SVG, since it doesn't impose any security threats that I'm aware of.

Comment: Do you have some sample questions and/or answers from around the SE network that demonstrates that this feature would have helped the quality of those posts a lot, instead of posting an image?

Comment: You're very specific when saying "instead", because it doesn't make the post different, it makes _writing it_ faster, and thus making it more likely to use visual/graphic explanations, and thus improving the quality of the question

Comment: @rene  I have wanted this feature for a while.  I make my sketches off-line (which is terrible because it's a non-portable solution) and It's not possible for others to correct or annotate my sketches.  Here are two examples of recent sketches I have submitted http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/41605/4565  http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/41585/4565

Comment: @rene  for example, I wanted to add "feet" to the jig sketch to clarify an edit, but it wasn't worth the hassle.

Comment: This is a [similar question and it's answer...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157435/158100)

Comment: in before svg penor.