# Image embed button doesn't like SVGs

Tags: feature-request, images

[image: Failed to upload image; the format is not supported]

Shouldn't it fall back to directly using the URL as source instead of uploading to imgur? Currently you need to manually type in image syntax.

Comment: This dialog currently only uploads to Imgur by design. Falling back to the actual URL instead of attempting an upload would be a feature request (and a debatable one at that - we upload to Imgur to prevent broken images).

Comment: @AnnaLear Okey. But if it don't work, then it's pre-breaking the images by discouraging SVG use and decreasing the likelihood that an image would be used at all.

Comment: Using "from web" reuploads your image to imgur, and it doesn't support svgs. Just to embed the image, without reuploading, use: `![description](address)` or `<img src="address">` - HTML syntax.

Comment: @nicael I don't think many people know that syntax (by design so people upload to imgur, preventing image rot?).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads