# Autosuggestion doesn't work for short headers

Tags: bug, duplicate-suggestions

When I was asking https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288888/309650 question, list  **Questions that may already have your answer** was not shown. But as soon as I posted a question, I've seen [Allow SVG image uploads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92568/309650) on the top of **Related** list. I'd like to see it before posting, not after.

[According to](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288888/upload-svg-file#comment937743_288888) @ShadowWizard the problem is that the title was too short:

> @PatrickHofman no, that's not the case as far as I can see. The problem is the title is too short, so it doesn't trigger the matching questions mechanism. Adding few letters when asking solves this:
>
> [image]

Comment: Yup, it's triggered after 17 characters, while minimum title length is 15.